# Programming the Atmel Mega 328P-AU 32 MLF (QFN) using the Arduino ISP

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, atmel, atmega328p

I have successfully managed to program both a (DIP)Mega168A-PU and a (DIP)Mega328PU using another (DIP)Mega328P-PU ISP.

This is the configuration that works for both DIP formats (168A-PU & 328P-PU):
[image]
[image]

No capacitors or resistors required. 
Now, following the same logic, this is what I have for the (QFN)328P-AU:
[image]

First thing I've noticed is that the QFN version has 2 VCCs and 3 GNDs, so I connected everything to the same PWS and GND. I tried to flush it using the Arduino IDE with the clock option set to both 8Mhz internal and 1Mhz internal - same unsuccessful result.

The avrdude complains about the device signature being 0x000000:
[image]

[image: Breakout board for the QFN Atmel Mega 328P-AU]

This is what I'd like to know: Do I have all the pints properly connected? Is it safe to assume that if the DIP version works fine using this pin configuration, the same thing should happen with the QFN? Is there something I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: The 0000000 device signature suggests either SPI is not connected or device lacks VCC/GND. Even with incorrect config flags, device signagure sould read as a constant. I've successfully flashed qfn ATmega328's, but not without bypass caps on the supply, near the chip. Is anything else attached to the SPI pins?

Comment: Well, did you check if the bottom pad is necessary for this?

Comment: @MarkU, thanks for your comment. The ISP (Arduino UNO) does not have anything else attached to it - except for the 4 programming GPIO pins + the 5V and GND. I will try to add a 220 uF and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Actually a ceramic 0.1uF with very short lead length, will do more good than a big AlElec bulk cap. The issue is fast transient currents, which happen whenever the SPI or other signals switch.

Comment: Check Sparkfun for Arduino Pro Mini: this is much closer to what you're trying to build.

Comment: As was mentioned previously 0.1uF caps close to the chip. For good measure connect AVCC. Where did the chip come from? Could the chip be configured for an external clock? This would cause the chip to fail programming.

Comment: ~vini_i, the chip I harvested myself from an Arduino Nano. On the Nano (same chip) I have successfully managed to flash the 328 a couple of times, so I know the chip works fine; then I decided to attach it to that breakout PCB.
@WesleyLee, the back of the MCU has no pad, non that I can see. I will remove the chip and specifically take another look at it. I thought about that as well, as in the data-sheet they make reference to "attaching the back pad to the GND", but I didn't see anything. I'll double-check.
~MarkU, I only have a few 220 uF(s) - ceramic. I'll try those if not I'll buy more.

Comment: Oh wait, the TQFP AFAIK does not have pads on the bottom. Which leads me to the following point, the drawing you are looking at is of a QFN/MLF not a TQFP. Not sure if the pinout is the same.